# How do I import a .discomap file into my project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

In an old solution, I have a folder called `App_WebReferences`, it contains another folder called `ReportExecution`. This contains a file called `ReportExection2005.discomap` and this file has a symbol of a web service.

And finally inside this file I have a `ReportExection2005.wsdl`.

I want to do the same thing on the new solution, but I only could import the `.wsdl` file, not the `.discomap`. I don't know if it has to be done automatically or I should create that folders by myself.

My `using ReportService;` is not being recognized by any kind way that I import a web service. I tried using "Add Web References", "Add existing file". Nothing works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Dialogs]

Right-click the project in the solution explorer, and choose "Add Service Reference...".  In that window, click "Advanced". In that window, click "Add Web Reference..."

That should probably get you there.

If not, read up about using wsdl.exe to generate the discomap.